# Flutter: How to color the data displayed from JSON according to the declarations

Tags: json, listview, flutter, dart, colors

this is json file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "United States",
    "continent": "North America"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Germany",
    "continent": "Europe"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "continent": "Europe"
  }
]
```

I want to set the condition as follows:

**1. Countries in North America (United States) will use
    `CotinentColor.NA`

 2. Countries in Europe (Germany & United Kingdom)
    will use `CotinentColor.EU`**

So what do I have to do?

This is custom_color file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContinentColor {
  static const Color NA = Color(0xFFFF9E80);
  static const Color EU = Color(0xFF2196F3);
  static const Color Asia = Color(0xFFE0E0E0);
}
```

this is the main file:

```
                        ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: countries.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      countries[index].country,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color:,
                                          // How to apply color according follow the conditional
                                    )
                                  ]));
                            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the boilerplate, you can create your extension method, like this:

```
extension ContinentExtension on String {
  Color get color{
    switch (this.toUpperCase()) {
      case "EUROPE":
        return ContinentColor.EU;
      case "NORTH AMERICA":
        return ContinentColor.NA;
      case "ASIA":
        return ContinentColor.Asia;
      default:
        return Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
  }
}

String americaCon = "North America";

print("Europe".color);
print(americaCon.color);

color: countries[index].continent.color;
```

For assets filename mapping, try this way:

```
extension AssetsExtension on String {
  String get asset => this.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_");
}

main(){
  print("North America".asset); //north_america
  print("Europe".asset); //europe
}
```

Comment: This method is great, can I do it to access assets from the string? I will need to switch it `toLowerCase` and replace the "spacebar" with "_". Ex. A string is "North America" => "north_america" to match the file name in assets. Can you help me? : D

Comment: Wow, It's incredible. You saved my life. Thank you for letting me know about it xD

Comment: How about one more case: replace "spacebar" and " ' " (apostrophe key) with "_". Ex: "let's go" => "let_s_go"  Pls help me ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try use map like this :

```
var colors = { "NA":Color(0xFFFF9E80), "EU":Color(0xFF2196F3) [,…..,key_n:value_n] }
```

then access like this

```
colors["NA"];....colors["EU"];
```

Answer (score 0):

An if statement and removing the 'const' constructors may solve your problem:

```
color: countries[index].continent == 'Europe' ? ContinentColor.EU : countries[index].continent == 'North America' ? ContinentColor.NA : ContinentColor.Asia,
```

or using a function:

```
Color colorRule(String continent){
  if(continent == 'Europe'){
    return ContinentColor.EU;
  }
  else if(continent == 'North America'){
    return ContinentColor.NA;
  }
  else{
    return ContinentColor.Asia;
  }
}

//in your list view:
color: colorRule(countries[index].continent);
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thank you so much. One more question, can we put it into a new class Ex. `ColorRule()` and call it out in `ListView` to make it neat and easy to see?

Comment: @Kel just updated the answer, but I putted inside a function, which you can put inside a class if you want